# rmarkdown not printing LaTeX on github

Tags: r, git, github, latex, r-markdown

I pushed the html output of my rmarkdown code to github with

```
output: 
   html_document:
     keep_md: true
```

which gave me the output I wanted, however, none of the comments that were typed in LaTeX were displayed in their natural form. I'm not sure if this is possible, but just curious if there is a way around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GFM does not include LaTeX support.](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/274)